# restrict keyword only to write buffers?

Tags: c

Does `restrict` keyword makes sense only to the pointers that we write to?

I often see the usage of `restrict` for both read and write buffers. for example in memcpy function,

`void* memcpy( void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t count );`.

If we remove `restrict` to src, do we change the functionality of this function?

In general, if we have a function
 `void fun(float * a, float *b .....);` when only `a` is modified, do we need `restrict` for other pointers too?

Comment: @Chris, to all global variables visible within this translation unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does restrict keyword makes sense only to the pointers that we write to?

No. `restrict` keyword also makes sense to pointers that we read from.

> If we remove restrict to src, do we change the functionality of this function?

`restrict` has no effect on [functionality](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/functionality). `restrict` doesn't change the "the tasks that software program is able to do".

Additionally, `restrict` did not exist before C99, yet `memcpy` had the same functionality.

> if we have a function  void fun(float * a, float *b .....); when only a is modified, do we need restrict for other pointers too?

You never "need" `restrict`. It's an addition, that you can add in specific situations to achieve better performance, given that the requirements of `restrict` are held. The requirement of "not modifying other pointers" is not enough to validate using `restrict`.

In the case of `memcpy`, `dest` and `src` are not allowed to overlap.

Related: there are situations, where compiler can infer non-aliasing of pointers given only some pointers are `restrict`. Such a case is discussed in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict in section "Function parameter", but the link is overall related and recommended to read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I admit that the question is bit vague. If possible, could you please give an example where adding restrict to read buffer would effect the performance ?

Comment: `could you please give an example where adding restrict to read buffer would effect the performance ?` https://godbolt.org/z/hEb5bxWh6 The function `fast` is optimized to use SIMD operations `movups` `movapd` by gcc. Overall, may be your point is, `restrict` is not really useful when the function does _no writes_ at all. Overall, _aliasing_ is a property is between some two things.

Comment: Re “`restrict` keyword also makes sense to pointers that we read from”: But only if **something** writes to the pointed-to memory. `restrict` does nothing (imposes no requirements) if the pointed-to memory is not modified during execution of the associated block.

Answer (score 1):

> Does `restrict` keyword makes sense only to the pointers that we write to?

The behavior of the compiler may be different if a pointer to memory that is only read is qualified with `restrict`. Consider:

```
void foo(char * restrict P, char *Q)
{
    printf("%d\n", *P);
    *Q = 3;
    printf("%d\n", *P);
}
```

The `restrict` tells the compiler that, since `P` is used to access `*P`, then, if the object at `P` changes by any means, the change will be based on `P` in some way.<sup>1</sup> In the above routine, the compiler can see that nothing based on `P` writes to `*P`, and therefore it may conclude `*P` does not change between the first `printf` and the second. Therefore, it can cache the value in a processor register instead of reloading it from memory for the second `printf`. Without `restrict`, the compiler would have to either reload `*P`, test whether `P` equaled `Q`, or know by some other means (analysis of the calls to `foo`) that `P` did not equal `Q`.

> `void* memcpy( void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t count );`.
>
> If we remove `restrict` to src, do we change the functionality of this function?

`restrict` should never change the semantics of a function. It should merely inform the compiler about the circumstances in which the function will be called. So the question should be will removing `restrict` from `src` make any changes to what the compiler can do?

The answer is no, but this is because of the specifics of `memcpy`, not because of the meaning of `restrict`.

First, `restrict` does nothing in a parameter declaration that is not in a function definition. `void memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t count);` and `void memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);` are actually compatible declarations because parameter qualifiers are ignored when determining function compatibility. The qualifier needs to appear in a function definition to have effect on its parameters.

Second, `memcpy` has only one other pointer parameter, and it is marked `restrict` and is used to change memory, so the compiler already knows that `src` will not be used to access any of the same memory as `dest`. Hypothetically, `memcpy` might internally write to some static buffer, and qualified `src` with `restrict` would inform the compiler that `src` does not point to that buffer, but that is not a realistic implementation of `memcpy`. Similarly, the qualifier would tell the compiler that `src` does not point to any of the memory `memcpy` uses inside itself, such as a local variable used as a loop counter, but the compiler can (if `memcpy` is written in C) see that already from the `memcpy` source code.

In other routines with additional pointer parameters or that access static memory or perhaps memory pointed to by pointers loaded from other memory (also static memory or memory pointed to by the parameters), then qualifying `src` (a parameter used only to read memory) with `restrict` can tell the compiler it may make some optimizations.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> For example, using a pointer copied from `P` produces a pointer based on `P`, as in `char *Z = P; *Z = 4;`.